# Item specific permisions in an ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

I'm creating my first site in ASP.NET MVC and I'd like to know how I can setup access rights or roles based on a specific item for a specific user.

My site has projects and users where each user can be a member of one or more projects. Each user that is a member of a project will be assigned to some number of roles in relation to that project. But each user may be assigned different roles for each project they are a member of.

Is there anyway I can take advantage of the built in membership roles to do something like this? From what I see a user's assigment to a role applied to the entire site, not a specific item like a project.

I was thinking of creating roles by concatenating the ProjectId and the project role into a single combined role such as 3213ProjectEditor. So then later I could use `User.IsInRole(currentProject.ID+"ProjectEditor")` to determine if as user is an editor in currentProject. This seems like a hack to me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in-built Authorization provider that uses the existing Role and User classes, is too tied up to Request and Response and the underlying Http connection. So it's not a good idea to use these classes for your case.

However you can get the inbuilt classes source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for reference, and build your own domain models.